# How to get trait's extended superclass/trait in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, inheritance, traits

I am trying to answer practice question from Book "Scala for Impatient 2nd Edition". The question is like this :

> Look at the `BitSet` class, and make a diagram of all its superclasses and traits.Ignore the type parameters (everything inside the […]).Then give the linearization of the traits.

The first impression I am thinking of is to get all `BitSet`'s superclasses/traits in a List.

To recursively get superclasses for a given class, I am managing to use below snippet

```
  def recurGetSupers(cls: Class[_]): List[Class[_]] = {
        cls :: Option(cls.getSuperclass).map(recurGetSupers).getOrElse(Nil)
  }
```

However, using above snippet will not give me a List of class, as expected, but below :

```
scala> recurGetSupers(classOf[scala.collection.BitSet])
res0: List[Class[_]] = List(interface scala.collection.BitSet)
```

So, my question is how to get superclasses or trait for the given trait ?

Comment: I think the idea of the exercise was not to made a program, but to look at the [documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/BitSet.html) of the class and start _"drawing "_  the diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Scala traits correspond to Java interfaces. So to get them you need the [`getInterfaces`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getInterfaces().) method. In Scala terms, it returns an `Array[Class[_]]` which will get implicitly converted to a `Seq` and you can call `toList` on it.